# Add new column including formula

Tags: vba, excel

Good Day,

I am trying to add a column on the sheet that I am creating including the formula of the selected column.
As per checking surfing for some codes I saw this,

```
Sub InsertRows() 

Dim Rng As Long 
Dim lngA As Long 
Dim lngB As Long 

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 

Rng = InputBox("Enter number of rows required.") 

If Rng = 0 Then Exit Sub 

Range(ActiveCell.Offset(1), ActiveCell.Offset(Val(Rng), 0)).EntireRow.Insert 

 '// How many formulas To copy down?
 '// From A  To last entry In row.
lngB = ActiveCell.Row 
lngA = Cells(lngB, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 
Range(Cells(lngB, 1), Cells(lngB + Val(Rng), lngA)).FillDown
```

this code really suits my need, however after trying several times, i am not able to convert it as column function. may I ask for your help to convert this?
thank you so much

Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

```
Sub InsertCols()
Dim Rng As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Rng = InputBox("Enter number of rows required.")

If Rng = 0 Then Exit Sub

Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1), ActiveCell.Offset(0, Val(Rng))).EntireColumn.Insert

ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Copy
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1), ActiveCell.Offset(0, Val(Rng))).EntireColumn.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```